# Could someone please explain this code to me? Why do I get a 0 instead of 16?

Tags: bit-manipulation

This code outputs 12480.. Why? I expected it will print 124816. Could someone explain that to me?

```
int main()
    {
        char c = 48;  // From ASCII one can find that char 48 represents 0.
        int i , mask = 1;
        for(i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
           {
                printf("%c", c|mask); // Here print the char formatted output 
                mask = mask << 1;
            } 
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: *Why* do you expect it will print 124816? (You could also reformulate this question to the much simpler circumstance of just the fifth time through the loop, which is where you're seeing something that apparently you don't expect...)

Comment: Yes. Not only for 5th time but if I change the for loop to for(i=1;i<=6;i++) I get same output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing **one** variable as `char`, you will never get `16` (which is **two** characters) out of that.

You have `48 = 110000`, when you `bitwise-or` it with `1` you get `110001 = 49` which when translated from ASCII to a `char` would be equal to character `1`.

The next time you get `110000 | 10 = 110010 = 50` which is `2`.

This goes on until you reach 5th iteration when `110000 | 10000 = 110000 = 48` which is `0`.

Comment: Thanks. I understood the mistake I made. I was doing an OR with 0 but I should have done that with the binary version of 48.

Comment: Yes. I did that now.. Probably using this for the first time.